# echo background-image inline style not showing

Tags: php, html, css

why is echoing background-image url does not work?
I'm trying to make each div with the same class have different background image

```
<?php
echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image :url(\"img1.jpg\"); '>$r[head]</div>";
 ?>
```

here is the list of codes I've tried after searching for solutions :

```
echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image :url(\"img1.jpg\"); '>$r[head]</div>";

echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image :url(\'img1.jpg\');'>$r[head]</div>";

echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image :url(\"img1.jpg\");'>$r[head]</div>";

echo '<div class="paket_title" style="background-image:url(\"img1.jpg\");">$r[head]</div>';

echo '<div class="paket_title" style="background-image:url(\'img1.jpg\');">$r[head]</div>';

echo '<div class="paket_title" style="background-image:url('img1.jpg');">$r[head]</div>';

echo '<div class="paket_title" style="background-image:url('img1.jpg');">$r[head]</div>';

echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image:url('img1.jpg');'>$r[head]</div>";

echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image:url("img1.jpg");'>$r[head]</div>";

echo '<div class="paket_title" style="background-image:url(img1.jpg);">$r[head]</div>';

echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image:url(img1.jpg);'>$r[head]</div>";

echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image :url(\"img1.jpg\"); '>" . $r['head'] . "</div>";
```

none of the above code is showing the image. I put the image in the same directory with this php file, even copy pasted the image to every subdirectory of my website folder.

here is the full code for this :

```
<?php
 if ($_GET['module']=='paketusaha'){
 $paket = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM paket_usaha ORDER BY id_paket DESC LIMIT 5");
  while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($paket)){
  $id_panel=1;
  $bg=$r['bgcolor'];
switch ($bg) {
  case "red" :
  echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image :url(\"img1.jpg\"); '>$r[head]</div>";
  break;

  case "blue" :
  echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image :url(\"img2.jpg\"); '>$r[head]</div>";
  break;

  case "yellow" :
  echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image :url(\"img2.jpg\"); '>$r[head]</div>";
  break;


}


 echo "
 <img src='paket_usaha/$r[gambar]'></img>
  <div class='harga-pkt'>$r[judul]</div>
   <div id='container'>
    <div class='expandable-panel' id='cp-$id_panel'>
    <div class='expandable-panel-heading bold' style='background-color : $r[headcolor]; color : white;' >
        <h2>klik disini untuk info paket<span class='icon-close-open'></span></h2>
     </div>
    <div class='expandable-panel-content' >
        <p>$r[isi]</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

`"; $id++;} ?>`

everything is working fine except the background-image not showing, I even changed it to just background and still no luck

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the page and seeing what is actually being generated? Checking the browser's console can help you too.

Comment: if you have live site url then please write here

Comment: well there is uncaught syntax error missing ) after argument list paket-usaha.html :283

but the html is generated by this php file, and after checking 3 times I did not found any missing )
everything is closed properly

this is not live yet, still in localhost

Comment: I can give you a screenshot here http://i.imgur.com/o1PogWI.jpg

Comment: there is no uncaught error on the image you gave. which line is the error? line 283?

Comment: as I said, I also did not found any missing ) in line 283
beside the html is generated by this php

Comment: Can you please add the link generated in url of inline background-image.. from html. Might be checking that can help

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

`echo "<div class='paket_title' style='background-image :url(\"img1.jpg\"); '>" . $r['head'] . "</div>";`

you must have a single quote for your $r['head'] and also a separator for your string and variable echo.

Comment: as you can see in my full code, there is no problem without separator for string and variable echo
just that the image no showing

here is the screenshot of my full code wroking if you're interested to look at it : http://i.imgur.com/o1PogWI.jpg

Answer (score 0):

alright I got a trick to make this work

first I make a CSS named after color for example :

```
.red {
   background-image : url("img1.jpg");
  }
 .blues {
   background-image : url("img2.jpg");
  }
```

now that the CSS is ready, just add the class to each div like this :

```
  <?php 
     switch ($bg) {
     case "red" :
      echo "<div class='paket_title red' >$r[head]</div>";
      break;

     case "blue" :
       echo "<div class='paket_title blues'>$r[head]</div>";
     break;

      }
```

that's it, each div now has different background image because each has specific CSS class that sets the background-image.

Answer (score 0):

1. first thing separate your css and php.
2. and use php in html like given below to avoid the errors of `'`and `"`.

   ```
   <div class='paket_title' style='background-image :url(\"img1.jpg\"); '><?php  echo $r[head];?></div>
   ```

and you can also use an if statement for this; first make css as you said in your answer.

```
<?php
while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($paket)){
   if($r % 2 == 0)){
?>
       <div class='paket_title red' ><?php echo $r[head];?></div>
<?php
   }else{
 ?>  
       <div class='paket_title blues' ><?php echo $r[head];?></div>
<?php
   }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: This is not to do with this post and I will delete this comment shortly, but please do not add bold (so liberally) to people's posts when you make an edit and please do not use backticks for anything except code. There's a thread about these types of edits on Meta right now. We have to spend a lot of time removing the formatting that you're inserting.